# Flash Builder 4.5 using completely wrong closing curly braces

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-builder

Here's the problem. For some strange reason, Flash Builder is deciding to use one of my if statement's closing curly brace for something else. It has decided that it wants that curly brace to close my class. This, in turn, breaks everything below it, because none of my private variables or methods are available. Here's the conditional...

```
if (!!_VOArray[0].length && !!_VOArray[1].length) {
  for (var i:uint = 0; i < _VOArray.length; i++) {
    if (!!_VOArray[1][i] && !!_VOArray[0][i].imageURL) {
      _VOArray[1][i].imageURL = _VOArray[0][i].imageURL;
      if (_VOArray[1][i].product == '') {
        _VOArray[1][i].product = _VOArray[0][i].product;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I comment this out, everything works swimmingly. Right now, the file says that the closing curly brace for the innermost conditional is correct. The wrapping if statement around that one, however, is closing off my whole class file.

Thoughts?

Comment: Looks okay from here. What is the exact error message you're getting? Also, have you tried commenting just portions of this out, like starting with just the inner if block to narrow the scope even further?

Comment: Thought it relevant to mention, I am using Flash Builder 4.5, but I am using the new Flash Builder 4.6 SDK.

Comment: @jmort253 I have tried commenting sections out, and retyping the entire file in a different view class. There is not an error. Flash is just treating the rest of the document after this as a different file. It even places new imports after this block and all private variables are not available after.

Comment: I might be exposing a hole in my knowledge, but I don't see a double ! operator in the docs http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html. I had assumed that this was some sort of bitwise or strict operator, but it doesn't seem to be. What are you using that operator for, and what happens if you use a different expression to get at the same thought? I pasted your code into FB and removed one of each pair of !!. When I clicked on each bracket, FB was then able to highlight the corresponding other bracket.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to use them as existential operators, forcing whatever variable I was checking into a boolean. It works perfectly in Javascript, so I just assumed. Anyways, if you make an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: You could also put parentheses around the inner expression, if you just want to do this: `!(!_VOArray[0].length)`

Answer (score -1):

The Adobe documentation don't have the operator `!!` (@Amy Blnkership), you are trying to test a "inverse value of inverse value of" so.. just remove then.

Maybe the Flash Builder has entering on quirks, he has a handful of quirks, like this:

http://goto0.cubelogic.org/a/205

you have try this?:

```
if (!!_VOArray[0].length && !!_VOArray[1].length) {
  for (var i:uint = 0; i < _VOArray.length; i++) {
    if (!!_VOArray[1][i] && !!_VOArray[0][i].imageURL) {
      _VOArray[1][i].imageURL = _VOArray[0][i].imageURL;
      if (_VOArray[1][i].product == '') _VOArray[1][i].product = _VOArray[0][i].product;
    }
  }
}
```